# How to get the text index of an element within a parent

Tags: javascript, html, string, text, offset

Let's say I have the following html:

```
<div>
     <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
     <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum <i>faucibus</i> dolor auctor.</p>
</div>
```

See the buried `<i>`? I would like to get it's text offset in relation to the parent `<div>`, including all of the `<p>` tags and whitespace, but not including the parent `<div>`. In this example, the text offset would be 225-ish.

Is this doable with javascript?

Edit: Okay a little background. I have the full html saved as a string in a database so I know the exact content. I also have access to the actual `<i>` dom element. Now I need to match that dom element to its text offset.

Comment: everything is doable with javascript

Comment: You can probably get *something*, but that something will not be reliable across multiple browsers. Anything that works directly with HTML will be inconsistent, because browsers do not think in HTML: they convert the HTML into DOM. Particularly with whitespace, the precise output will vary when converted back into HTML.

Comment: grab the div object, use `innerHTML` for the content and `indexOf('<i>')` for finding the index the part you need (+3)

Comment: What happens if there are multiple `<i>` tags with the same content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Performance-wise

I would reccomend the pure way.
[**JSPerf:** See it by yourself](http://jsperf.com/jquery-lastindex-vs-purejs)

---

### [Pure Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/9GYVs/1/)

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
/* The index */
alert(div.innerHTML.lastIndexOf('<i>'));
/*The remaining HTML of the div*/
alert(div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.lastIndexOf('<i>'),div.innerHTML.length));
```

### Alternative

```
document.getElemendById('myFirstItalicText');
```

---

### [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/9GYVs/2/)

```
alert($('div').html().indexOf('<i>'));
```

---

### [Alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/9GYVs/3/)

Add an `id` or a `class` to your `<i>` elements to find them easily.

```
$('#myFirstItalicText').css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: Okay I have considered using the `indexOf()` method, however I fear that there may be multiple `<i>` tags and they may have the same content.

Comment: @TylerJohnson Then just create a temporary variable with a value of 0 that'll store the latest index found and in your loop make sure the new index is *higher* than the variable.

Comment: But how do I know that the nth element is the one I want if they are all the same?

Comment: You might want to get the substring between the `indexOf('<i>')` and `indexOf(</i>)` and check if the content is the one you want. Otherwise you might want to add IDs or classes to those.

Comment: Oh an id is a clever way to do it. Basically, force it to be unique and then use `indexOf()`.

Comment: @TylerJohnson I will add it to the answer then!

Comment: If you used an `id` then I imagine you would remove the need to find the index at all.

Comment: I am marking this as the solution, however it doesn't totally solve my problem. I ended up using a totally different method to solve my original problem, however for this particular question, the answer is using `indexOf()` *after* forcing the element to be unique.

`myITag.attr("id", "veryUniqueID");
    parentEl.html().indexOf($("<div>").append(myITag).html());
    myITag.removeAttr("id");`

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer, based on your requirements, is *no*.

The browser only provides the HTML of elements as a convenience, not as a substitute for the DOM API. The only way to reliably retrieve and manipulate elements is through the DOM.

You should only think of HTML as *metadata* for elements in the DOM.

Comment: See my comment below. I don't want to use `indexOf()` because there may be multiple matching `<i>` tags with the same content.

Comment: I think this is a fundamental issue with your question. You really can't work with HTML like that in the browser.